# Morphing of CSS classes React/ Webpack

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack

If you inspect the [Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.co.in/) site you will see that somehow classnames morphed into single names(alphanumeric). What is the name of this technique and is it done from code level or build level.

[image]

Comment: I read it somewhere, while coding we have follow a specific structure and then webpack will morph them as per need.

Comment: @Gags any link / docs or any other pointer that i can look into

Comment: https://develoger.com/how-to-obfuscate-css-class-names-with-react-and-webpack-20e2b5c49cda?gi=918ccb4883ed

https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules

Comment: @Gags thx a lot please add this as an answer and i will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read it somewhere, while coding we have follow a specific structure and then webpack will morph them as per need.

Here are few links for your reference:

https://develoger.com/how-to-obfuscate-css-class-names-with-react-and-webpack-20e2b5c49cda?gi=918ccb4883ed

https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules